# why does the same ordering behave the other way around in sorted array and priority queue?

Tags: scala

```
implicit object valueOrdering extends Ordering[Int] {
  def compare(t1: Int, t2: Int): Int = {
    t1.compare(t2)
  }
}
val arr3 = Array(3,5,1,9,15,2)
val costPQ = mutable.PriorityQueue.empty[Int]
costPQ.++=(arr3)
costPQ.clone().dequeueAll.mkString(",").foreach(print)
println
arr3.sorted.mkString(",").foreach(print)
```

please look at the code above; i got

15,9,5,3,2,1

1,2,3,5,9,15

after i ran it.
so can anyone shed light upon how sorted array and priority queue behave the other way around with the same ordering? Thanks a million.

Comment: Element with highest  priority is dequeued first. Not sure what throws you off about this.

Comment: yes, i see that. but i am still a little confused about how to understand ordering in priority queue and sorted collection

Comment: What specifically confuses you? Its descending in one case, and ascending in the the other respectively

Comment: why is it descending in priority queue whereas ascending in sorted collection?

Comment: Because that is the definition of priority queue

Comment: If you _see_ that element with highest is dequeued first, then you must also "see" why the order is descending ... because it literally means exactly the same thing.

Comment: yes, priority queue always serves the element with the highest priority. but how to understand the ordering's behavior in sorted collection?

Comment: Hmm, collection sorting uses provided ordering as is.  Priority queue uses provided ordering but negates result of the ordering ( *-1)